# Is it possible to implement In-App Purchases only for a subset of countries?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

Is there a way to use In-App Purchases such that they're NOT available in the USA, and at the same time figure out if they're available or not - and if not, perform special tasks for customers in the USA who can't use them?

Comment: You definitely can publish several versions of an app with different AppIDs for different countries. But I'd like to see real answer also. :)

Comment: Heard rumors Apple might reject "clone apps" for whatever reason.

Comment: I think that you can talk to Apple about this. They must not be clones, but the same app. In every store there must be only one of them. Location detection sometimes is not acceptable. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CLLocationManager to find the users location and then use MKReverseGeocoder to figure out what country they are in.

Some people will deny access to location information. As a backup you could use the language that the current device is in (but there are some obvious issues with this approach):

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes
```

Then you just need to use a conditional statement:

```
if(in USA){ 
  do whatever, don't allow in-app purchases
} else {
  allow in app purchases
}
```

Comment: Or: If Location services don't work / are disabled, handle it like if the user was in the USA. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could send a product request in the background, and only display the purchase button if something comes back. The drawback is that there could be issues (store outages, network issues, you take the product down temporarily) that would make the product request fail, so you'd have to design the alternative UI appropriately.

```
SKProductsRequest *productRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:productId]]; 
productRequest.delegate = self;
[productRequest start];


-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    if ([[response products] count] > 0) {
        // display purchase link
    } else {
        // display alternative UI
    }
}
```